# i am having issue with my adapter in android java application "duplication of items "

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

so i want to have a layout that helps to delete images
but after performing deltation my items other then deleted one is duplicated
and deleted item stays same, but re-opening the activity fixes the issue

I am using firebase,but seems like issue is with adapter ,if I try to perform deletion on that duplicated items deletion is performed but to the other non intended items ,feels like list index for those number duplicated items are changed that's why

here is adapter code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.jkstudio.scaj.R;
import com.jkstudio.scaj.common.FullImageView;

import java.util.List;

public class GalleryAdminAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdminAdapter.GalleryAdminViewAdapter> {


    private final Context context;
    private List<GalleryAdminData> list;
    private DatabaseReference Drefrance, DRef;
    private StorageReference Srafrance, SRef;
    boolean doesConfirmed_deletion = false;


    public GalleryAdminAdapter(Context context, List<GalleryAdminData> list) {

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public GalleryAdminViewAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout_admin_gallery_image, parent, false);
        return new GalleryAdminViewAdapter(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GalleryAdminViewAdapter holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {


        try {

            Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position).getDurl()).into(holder.gallery_imageView);
            holder.gallery_imageView.setOnClickListener(v ->
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, FullImageView.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageurl_pass", list.get(position).getDurl());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "FAILED to load image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("====>Error", "Glide image load in galleryadmin" + e.getMessage());


        }
        holder.deletebtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            boolean delete = alertDelete(position);
            if (delete)
            {
                list.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }


        });


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    private boolean alertDelete(int positionrefalert)
    {

        doesConfirmed_deletion = false;
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setMessage("Delete this Image ?");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("confirm", (dialog1, which) ->
        {
            doesConfirmed_deletion = true;
            try {
                Srafrance = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Gallery");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("====>Error", "get gallery Srafrance" + e.getMessage());
            }


            SRef = Srafrance.child(list.get(positionrefalert).getSfilename());

            SRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(unused ->
            {
                // Toast.makeText(context, "image delete-cloud", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("====>Success", "gallery image delete done");
            }).addOnFailureListener(e ->
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "image delete-cloud failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("====>Error", "gallery image delete failed" + e.getMessage());

            });


            try {
                Drefrance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Gallery");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("====>Error", "get Db refrance gallery delete " + e.getMessage());
            }


            DRef = Drefrance.child(list.get(positionrefalert).getCategory()).child(list.get(positionrefalert).getKey());
            DRef.removeValue()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task ->
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("====>Success", "gallery image data delete done");
                    }).addOnFailureListener(e ->
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong -Srefrance-DN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("====>Error", "delete gallery image data failed" + e.getMessage());
            });


            //    notifyItemRemoved(positionrefalert);

                notifyDataSetChanged();


        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancle", (Idialog, which) ->
        {
            Idialog.cancel();

        });

        AlertDialog Adialog = null;
        try {
            Adialog = dialog.create();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.show();
        }

        return doesConfirmed_deletion;
    }



    public class GalleryAdminViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView gallery_imageView;
        Button deletebtn;

        public GalleryAdminViewAdapter(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            gallery_imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_item_imageView);
            deletebtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_delete_btn);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I do not think it is the problem of adapter your list somehow has duplicate items

Comment: no i dont have duplicate items in database I checked while executing actions

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are never actually deleting the list item. Your adapter has your list data defined as:

```
private final List<GalleryAdminData> list;
```

But in your `alertDelete` function you are only deleting the reference stored in `FirebaseStorage`. There's no code to remove the item from `list`.

EDIT: Make sure you call the following:

```
list.removeAt(holder.absoluteAdapterPosition)
notifyItemRemoved(holder.absoluteAdapterPosition)
```

Instead of using the position passed to `alertDelete` so that you are deleting the correct item and notifying the list about new positions.

A few other notes:

- You shouldn't pass in and store a reference to `Context`. It can result in resource leaks. You can get the context from any view via [`View.getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View?hl=en#getContext()). In `onCreateViewHolder`, use `parent` and in your ViewHolder, use [`itemView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#itemView).
- [notifyItemRemoved](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemRemoved(int)) does not throw any exceptions, so there's no need to surround it with a `try-catch` block.
- Your code is very difficult to read. I suggest using Android Studio to reformat it (from the menu, *Code -> Reformat File... or Reformat Code*)

Comment: i am new to it so very unformatted, full of typo code, as you said deleting list object 
I have other adapters for the same things and there I didn't need to delete the list items and they just work fine

Comment: and thanks for other suggestion also

Comment: i tried removing item from list and even clearing whole list but neither worked still duplicate items

Comment: Post your updated code if you want help with that. There's absolutely no way that you can have a working adapter with a delete function that does not actually delete the list item and call the appropriate notify method.

Comment: can we go discord?
by correct notify I mean I just added  notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I added an edit to clarify how to delete the list item.

Comment: i did like what you mentioned in answer but still didn't workout
updated code in question

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to help in greater detail. I suggest you create a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Remove all of the Firebase stuff and unnecessary code, and see if you're still having problems. Then slowly add back what you need.